# Connect to Oracle using SQLDeveloper using OS Authentication on a remote machine

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, oracle-sql-developer

I reach my database server from my MacBook via SSH. You can login into this database as by using OS authentication.

```
MacBook:~ mangeles$ ssh oracle@10.10.1.64
oracle@10.10.1.64's password: 
Last login: Thu May 21 11:45:14 2015 from 172.31.12.51
[oracle@bd ~]$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [MF] ? PROD
[oracle@bd ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu May 21 11:46:17 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

I'm able to connect to the database using SQLDeveloper but I have to provide a username and a password. I can connect to all the databases as a SYS (through SSH) but I don't have the SYS password of all the databases and changing the password is not an option.

I want to know how I can use the OS Authentication in my SQLDev to login as I do in my terminal, without entering a password.

[image: This is the error i get]

Answer (score 1):

These are the default values related to this:

```
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
os_authent_prefix                    string      ops$
remote_os_authent                    boolean     FALSE
```

Set remote_os_authent to true:

```
alter system set remote_os_authent=true scope=spfile sid='*';
shutdown immediate
startup
```

Create a database user with your OS username, prefixed with the above value:

```
create user ops$mangeles identified externally;
grant create session to ops$mangeles;
```

This way you can log in without a password because of the remote OS authentication. The problem is, anyone can create an OS user named `mangeles` on any machine, and they will be able to log in without providing a password.

SYSDBA will not work with this type of authentication, if you try `grant sysdba to ops$mangeles`, you will get `ORA-01997: GRANT failed: user 'OPS$MANGELES' is identified externally`.

Comment: Setting `remote_os_authent` to `TRUE` is a very bad idea and your sentences on this should be bold and in red :-) And the parameter is deprecated in 11g and higher.

Answer (score 0):

When you login in the terminal, Oracle lets you in because the user `oracle` on the server `10.10.1.64` is a member of the `OSDBA` group on that machine.

When you connect from SQL Developer on your laptop, it's a remote connection so OS Authentication isn't normally possible. You might be able to use SSH Authentication, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/intro.htm#CHDEHFFB Maybe it's configurable when you click on the "Advanced..." button?